# How to fix discount amount directly in Odoo POS

Tags: odoo, fixed, point-of-sale, discount

When I tried to host odoo 9 points of sale, I am able to fix the discount in percentage.

But how can I set the discount in amount? There we can fix the amount to be paid. But this is not calculated as the discount. We need to resemble this discount in accounts also. And fixing the amount is not considered as the discount. When I checked some forums, it is said that we need to customise odoo to enable fixed amount discounts. I am a beginner in odoo development. So please help me to find a solution for this.

Thanks in advance!